# Multiline fields not working

Tags: 2010, content-type

I have the following content type definition and list definition, the description field should show me 4 lines, maxlength 255, but it always shows me One line one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Parent ContentType: Link (0x0105) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x01050095b7aa21bdb44df09b7f4ce6acbc17cf"
               Name="OST.HWT - CTMirageTeamsCIRCALinks"
               Group="Custom Content Types"
               Description="CTMirageTeamsCIRCALinks"
               Inherits="TRUE"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{A6A5709D-6F9A-49CE-B623-C1159251C50B}"
        Name="ExternalSiteDescription"
        DisplayName="Description"
        Required="False" NumLines="4"/>
      <RemoveFieldRef ID="{9da97a8a-1da5-4a77-98d3-4bc10456e700}" Name="Comments"  />


    </FieldRefs>

  </ContentType>
</Elements>



<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="OST.HWT - CIRCALinks" Direction="$Resources:core,Direction;" OrderedList="TRUE" Url="Lists/OST.HWT-CIRCALinks" BaseType="0" DisableAttachments="TRUE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentType ID="0x01050095b7aa21bdb44df09b7f4ce6acbc17cf" Name="OST.HWT - CTMirageTeamsCIRCALinks" Group="Custom Content Types" Description="CTMirageTeamsCIRCALinks" Inherits="TRUE" Version="0">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef ID="{A6A5709D-6F9A-49CE-B623-C1159251C50B}" Name="ExternalSiteDescription" DisplayName="Description" Required="False" />
        </FieldRefs>
      </ContentType>
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
      <Field ID="{82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31}" Name="LinkTitle" Hidden="FALSE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="LinkTitle">
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{bc91a437-52e7-49e1-8c4e-4698904b2b6d}" Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" Hidden="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="LinkTitleNoMenu">
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{081c6e4c-5c14-4f20-b23e-1a71ceb6a67c}" Name="DocIcon" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Type;" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="DocIcon">
      </Field>      
      <Field ID="{c29e077d-f466-4d8e-8bbe-72b66c5f205c}" Type="URL" Name="URL" DisplayName="$Resources:core,URL;" Required="TRUE" FromBaseType="TRUE" ShowInViewForms="FALSE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="URL">
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{9da97a8a-1da5-4a77-98d3-4bc10456e700}" Type="Note" Hidden="TRUE" Name="Comments" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Notes;" Sortable="FALSE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Comments">
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{2a9ab6d3-268a-4c1c-9897-e5f018f87e64}" ReadOnly="TRUE" Filterable="FALSE" Type="Computed" Name="URLwMenu" DisplayName="$Resources:core,URL;" DisplayNameSrcField="URL" ClassInfo="Menu" AuthoringInfo="$Resources:core,URLwEditMenu;" ListItemMenuAllowed="Required" LinkToItemAllowed="Prohibited" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="URLwMenu">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef Name="URL" />
          <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" />
          <FieldRef Name="FileRef" />
          <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" />
          <FieldRef Name="_EditMenuTableStart2" />
          <FieldRef Name="_EditMenuTableEnd" />
        </FieldRefs>
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{7A7F3660-D408-4734-9AA0-2D86E33D79AB}" ReadOnly="TRUE" Filterable="FALSE" Type="Computed" Name="URLwMenu2" DisplayName="$Resources:core,URL;" DisplayNameSrcField="URL" ClassInfo="Menu" AuthoringInfo="$Resources:core,URLwEditMenu; (old)" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="URLwMenu2">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef Name="URL" />
          <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" />
          <FieldRef Name="FileRef" />
          <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" />
          <FieldRef Name="_EditMenuTableStart" />
          <FieldRef Name="_EditMenuTableEnd" />
        </FieldRefs>
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{aeaf07ee-d2fb-448b-a7a3-cf7e062d6c2a}" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" ReadOnly="TRUE" Filterable="FALSE" Type="Computed" Name="URLNoMenu" DisplayName="$Resources:core,URL;" DisplayNameSrcField="URL" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="URLNoMenu">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef Name="URL" />
          <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" />
          <FieldRef Name="FileRef" />
          <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" />
        </FieldRefs>
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{a6a5709d-6f9a-49ce-b623-c1159251c50b}" Name="ExternalSiteDescription" Type="Text" DisplayName="Description" Required="FALSE" Group="Mirage Teams Columns" NumLines="4" />
      <Field ID="{503f1caa-358e-4918-9094-4a2cdc4bc034}" Name="Edit" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Edit;" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Edit">
      </Field>
    </Fields>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the list definition the `ExternalSiteDescription` field is defined as `Text`. `Text` fields are single lines with a configurable max length (via `MaxLength`).

To create a multiline field you must use the `Note` field type. With the `Note` type you can set the number of lines with `NumLines`. You can probably use `MaxLength` on Note field too. (i'm not completely sure, untested!)

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979575.aspx) for field types available in the `<Field>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't use the MaxLength property with a Notes field, it's not supported, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldmultilinetext_members.aspx)

Multiline fields are rendered as <textarea>'s and this HTML control doesn't support a maxlength property like an <input> field does.

Comment: +! - saved me a lot of hassle.